# The push notification switch is off in Setting.app after user choose to allow push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Did any one ever occur this issue? Should it only be a UI display issue? I mean the Setting.app UI did not refresh it self.

Our "register notification center" codes are as following:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                              if (granted) {
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                                  });
                                  if (![FBYPreferences instance].hasRequestAuthorizationForNotification) {
                                      [Taplytics logEvent:@"Accept Notification number" value:@(1) metaData:nil];
                                  }
                              }else {
                                  [TrackerHelper doTrackEvent:@"Notifiction Not Granted" withCategory:@"Notifiction" withLabel:@""];
                                  if (![FBYPreferences instance].hasRequestAuthorizationForNotification) {
                                      [Taplytics logEvent:@"Decline Notification number" value:@(1) metaData:nil];
                                  }
                              }
                              [FBYPreferences instance].hasRequestAuthorizationForNotification = YES;
                          }];
```

I look at these codes and think it is OK. Our PM said they can not receive the push notification after they saw the switch is off in Setting.app.

Do you have any suggestion for it. Your idea may solve it and I will really appreciate for it.

Update: we call the above code twice when app launching. Is it possible the reason? We remove the duplicated method call and only call above once.

Comment: Update: our QA can reproduce it and the device can not receive push notification even we choose allow push notification. And the switch is off in the Setting.app.

Comment: is it occurring in all ios versions ?? I remember having a similar issue long back, but then It was due to different registration process in ios9 and ios 10. I needed to handle both based on OS versions.

Comment: It is occurring in iOS 11.2 and above. Do you mean you only handle iOS 9 and use -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings] method? After you occurred the issue, you add support for iOS 10 and use the new api in UNUserNotificationCenter. Is it correct?